# Why does member function not hide type alias in base class when compiling with GCC?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++-concepts

I have the following C++20 program to demonstrate a difference in GCC and MSVC (I think MSVC is right on this one):

```
#include <utility>

struct base
{
  using get = void;
};

struct type_a : base
{
  int get(int i) const
  {
    return i;
  }
};

struct type_b : base
{
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto get_or_default(const T& obj, Args&&... args) -> decltype(obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
  return obj.get(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T>
  requires requires { typename T::get; } // should prevent get_or_default(a) from compiling successfully
int get_or_default(const T&)
{
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  const type_a a;
  const int i0 = get_or_default(a, 42);
  const int i1 = get_or_default(a); // no error with GCC 11.1, compile error with MSVC 14.29

  const type_b b;
  const int i2 = get_or_default(b);

  return i0 + i1 + i2;
}
```

`type_a` provides a member function `get()`. The indent is that the second overload of `get_or_default()` is never used for `type_a`, because `type_a::get` is not a type. `get_or_default(a, 42)` correctly returns `42`. `type_b` has no member function, but it inherits the nested type alias, so `type_b::get` is a type and `-1` is returned from `get_or_default(b)`.

The issue is that `get_or_default(a)` works on GCC. On MSVC this line gives the error:

*error C2672: 'get_or_default': no matching overloaded function found*

In my mind the error is correct. The first `get_or_default()` overload is not viable, because `type_a::get()` does not take zero arguments. The second `get_or_default()` overload should not be viable too, because the constraint `requires { typename T::get; }` is not met for member function `type_a::get`. With GCC however, `requires { typename T::get; }` is met for `T=type_a`. Note that the constraint `requires { typename type_a::get; }` outside of a template fails to compile on GCC too. Is this a bug in GCC?

Background: I'm trying to implement `receiver_adaptor` of [P2300R5 std::execution](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2300r5.html#spec-execution.snd_rec_utils.rcvr_adptr) which to my understanding relies on this to work (for example see `using set_value = unspecified;`). Follow up question: If this is a bug, is there a workaround to detect this situation correctly with GCC?

EDIT: I've just tried x86-64 clang 15.0.0 on Compiler Explorer and clang agrees with MSVC, that `get_or_default(a)` should not compile. Nevertheless, I still need a workaround for GCC.

Comment: here is a smaller example https://godbolt.org/z/6o7dorEdv

Comment: It is not specifically concept related, see https://godbolt.org/z/5zxx8hTxP

Comment: gcc also happily compiles [this example](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#example-4).

Comment: I have submitted a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107773)